# How to generate Hibernate query in Uppercase while am using JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

can Hibernate generate uppercase SQL?

I.e. some option which would make it send

```
SELECT TAB.NAME1 AS NAME_A, TAB.NAME2 AS NAME_B FROM TABLE_NAME AS TAB;
```

instead of current

```
select TAB.NAME1 AS name_a, TAB.NAME2 AS name_b from TABLE_NAME as table1_;
```

Am using IBM DB2 database

Hibernate need to generate complete query (even 'AS' Name) also in uppercase.

Comment: *Hibernate need to generate complete query (even 'AS' Name) also in uppercase.* Why?

Comment: Resultset am getting in JPQL query is giving invalid character for some special character. If I use Upper case of that special char as in TAble column then it is working fine.

Comment: Have you set the correct dialect?

Comment: Yes, org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect